# How to store a long array's value in to variales using php

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

How to save each value of the above array in a variable using PHP.

```
Array ( [0] => Abbottabad )
Array ( [0] => Faisalabad )
Array ( [0] => Gujranwala )
Array ( [0] => Hyderabad )
Array ( [0] => Islamabad )
Array ( [0] => Karachi )
Array ( [0] => Lahore )
Array ( [0] => Mangla )
Array ( [0] => Multan )
Array ( [0] => Muree )
Array ( [0] => Peshawar )
Array ( [0] => Quetta )
Array ( [0] => Rawalpindi )
Array ( [0] => Sialkot )
```

I have got these values form mysql. Now I want to store in to a variable in such a way that I cant print each value separately.

Comment: why you make separate array for each value?

Comment: From your output I guess this code is in a loop. And now you want to store these arrays in a variable, so you can't print them separately anymore ?!

Comment: try to be more specific.

Comment: Please do a `print_r($your_array_name)` so we can see what the array really looks like. Then add the output to your Question with an `edit`, dont put it in a comment. You dont need to move these values from the array, you can print data directly from the array

Answer (score 0):

Save these array into an array (I hope you are talking about array of objects that is returned by database), if not just save it in array to avoid static checks.

```
foreach($arrayResult as $key => $value){
 foreach($value as $dataArray){
   echo $dataArray;
 }
}
```